# On closing questions as "not constructive" and its counter-productivity

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, not-constructive

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096587/is-http-better-suited-to-be-stateless) yesterday on HTTP - I thought it was a valid question, yet it was closed for being "not constructive". I honestly do not understand exactly why this question was deemed inappropriate;  I asked a **technical** question which has **definitive** answers and I understand it does not contain/require code, but many of the questions on StackOverflow don't either so I don't think that's the reason. I disagree with the verdict, and I'm wondering what can be done in these scenarios to appeal and/or have the question reopened.

Furthermore, closing the question was obviously counter-productive as the end result was three users using comments to answer the question anyway. How is that any better than letting the users answer the questions properly?

**EDIT**

Also, please explain why these questions are any different in terms of subjectivity than what I asked:

[Advantages of atmega32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805383/advantages-of-atmega32)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459345/disadvantages-advantages-of-reflection

[Advantages Of MySQLi over MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171344/advantages-of-mysqli-over-mysql)

All of these questions have over 1k views and are not closed. All of them have a similar style to my question and yet they are open - I'm just trying to understand how the system works, yet it seems very inconsistent.

Comment: "**Are there advantages** to using a stateless protocol on the web that would otherwise make a non-stateless protocol **more favoured?**" - Note the emphasized parts, those are the subjective parts.  One man's treasure is another man's trash.  We've found that the applicability of the answers for these questions are highly unique to every individual, and therefore, not well-suited to the Stack Exchange system.

Comment: Commenting on downvotes is considered noise and should be refrained from.  Assuming who might have downvoted is folly as voting is *anonymous*.  That said, [voting on meta is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: With regards to your original comment on subjectivity, please see my edit; perhaps you can provide further insight on that.

Comment: Those other questions have been closed.  We simply don't know about *all* the not constructive questions out there, but we'll close them when we know about them.

Comment: @hesson: Those questions are old. The rules about the types of questions that are acceptable on Stack Overflow have changed over time, and we're still in the process of cleaning up all the bad ones that are still around from the before-times. Please do not take old questions as an invitation that those types of questions are acceptable. Always go by what the FAQ says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Debating Design

Your title might have been okay, but your real question was at the end. You wrote:

> Are there advantages to using a stateless protocol on the web that would otherwise make a non-stateless protocol more favoured?

In other words, you were asking a rather abstract question about the merits of stateful vs. stateless protocols. That is a polling question, almost by definition.

With some judicious editing, your question might fit [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). As it is currently written, though, I believe it was properly tagged as Not Constructive for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the Programmers suggestion - I'll try that in the future.

Comment: how Come title end difference weigh the same? not only but overweigh –